# lucene Regular expression for phone number and site urls

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to get a list of objects that include phone numbers and site URLs at elastic search based on Lucene's queries.

I used the following regex

1. for phone number
   ^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-s.]?[0-9]{3}[-s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$
2. for site URL

   [(http(s)?)://(www.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%.*+~#=]{2,256}.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%*+.~#?&//=]*)"

both of them are not working

Comment: `[-s.]` must probably be `[ .-]`, you do not actually expect `s` to be in a phone number. The second one should not start with `[`, no need to escape `+` in the character class, and you can reduce `//` to just `/` in the character class there.

Comment: Ok I used this:  ^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[ .-]?[0-9]{3}[ .-]?[0-9]{4,6}$ still retrieve nothing. 
for example, this is phone number that should appear in the search +(919)-367-788755